# Printing a pair out as a string

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I am trying to print out a string from a const pair I declared

```
using Collatz = pair<long, vector<long> >;
```

However, in this function, it allows me to print the first value with no problems. When I want to print the second value, it makes me add the & symbol to it which then prints out the address. How do I get around this so I can print out the actual value.

```
string Collatz_to_string(const Collatz &p) {
ostringstream oss;
oss << p.first << "," << p.second;
return oss.str();
}
```

> Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::__1::vector >' to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &

Comment: there is no overload for `operator<<` that takes a vector. you have to write your own

Comment: Yeah i fixed it, I just converted the vector to a string, and then printed it out.

Comment: the dupe is asking for `printf` but the answer is exhaustively discussing using `operator<<`

Comment: btw not sure what you want to have, but you dont need the detour via a `string`. You could simply instead of inserting the pair in a `ostringstream` insert it directly into `std::cout` (or whereever you want to insert it)